# Dell Inspiron 15, 3543 Five Beeps on startup - but starts fine

Tags: windows-10, boot, bios

I have a  Dell Inspiron 15, 3543.  As of a couple of days ago it started giving 3 or 2 loud beeps on startup between the BIOS/UEFI logo and the windows startup logo.

Entering the BIOS allows you to count the beeps correctly and it appears to be 5 beeps in total.

Windows itself continues to load fine.  The beeps seem to occur with and without mains power.

What do they mean?

Additional Notes:

I've ran the Windows Memory Diagnostic and that returned "The Windows Memory Diagnostic tested the computer's memory and detected no errors"

I've also removed the memory module air dusted the socket and replaced it with another working memory module and the beeping continued.

20/09/2016 - Question updated as I originally miscounted the beeps as four not five.

Comment: intriguingly i just restarted again and it's now down to 1 beeps.  The beeps are going down... I'm not sure if this is a good thing or if I should evacuate the building ;)

Comment: If the beeps are during BIOS/UEFI load, they don't have anything to do with Windows or Windows Updates. The beeps are likely the P.O.S.T. (power on self test) informing/warning you of something. Have you entered BIOS Setup to see if there are any warning messages in the log? Have you run any hardware diagnostics? Look up beep codes at Dell?

Comment: OK just entered the setup and it continued to beep 4 beeps on a cycle whilst I was in there.  As far as I can see there's no logging available from within the setup...  
I'm guessing the beeps were changing earlier simply because it depended on how fast Windows loaded.   I can now focus on the 4 beeps and see if I can convert that into something suitable for a human.

Comment: I couldn't find a Dell Inspiron 5200U model. You sure that's it? From what I found **[here](http://blog.parts-people.com/2014/06/25/dell-inspiron-15r-n5110-beep-codes-diagnostic-indicators/)** for a similar model, it might be memory failure. You might want to run a memory test.

Comment: Ah that would explain why my Googling failed...  You're right it's actually an Inspiron 15, 3543.  I've had too many Dell machines over the years - was looking at the CPU model! :S

Thanks.  I'll do a memory test.

Comment: Ran the Windows Memory Diagnostic and that returned
"The Windows Memory Diagnostic tested the computer's memory and detected no errors".  I'll double check nothings become dislodged...

Comment: The mystery continues.  I tried removing the memory chip and replacing it with one from another machine (air dusting the socket).  The beeping continues...

Comment: Please update your original post with all these updates. Most people won't read thru all these comments, therefore will not get all the details.

Comment: OK I miscounted the beeps!  It was five beeps not four.  Turns out that means the CMOS battery has gone.  I found a Youtube video to get at the battery which is not a simple task - and requires complete dismantling of the machine to get at the main board.  The battery is sat on top of the main board.  I used a volt meter on the battery and it was giving out 0 volts.  Replaced it and the issue has now gone.

Answer (score 0):

Through [CharlieRB's](https://superuser.com/users/97028/charlierb) comment which gave this [link](http://blog.parts-people.com/2014/06/25/dell-inspiron-15r-n5110-beep-codes-diagnostic-indicators/) I discovered the CMOS battery was the issue.
I replaced the CMOS Battery which involves disassembly the machine - for which there are various YouTube videos available.

The battery is a CR2032 battery an is on the top of the motherboard underneath the palm rest.  My battery was completely dead and reading 0 volts on a voltmeter.